# Fill empty cells of dataframe with values from other dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, fill

I would like to fill empty cells of a dataframe.
The cells should be filled with values or strings to be found in a other dataframe
where the "Y" is the same.
I thought about using a dicitonary, but cannt get it to work.
The desires ouput would be to fill the emtpy cell in df1 (row 1) with the value "7".
The sorting and the length of the dataframes will not be the same.
df1 will also contain duplicates.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Z': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'],
                    'Y': [6,'',8, 6, 6]
                   })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Z': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                   'Y': [6, 7, 8, 9, 1],
                   })
df1
Z  Y
0  a  6
1  b   
2  c  8
3  a  6
4  a  6
df2
Z  Y
0  a  6
1  b  7
2  c  8
3  d  9
4  e  1
```

what I tried:

```
dic = df2.set_index('Z').to_dict()['Y']
df1.replace({'Y': {'' :dic}})
```

I get the following error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' " 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good first question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace only matched rows by mask for test empty rows by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), if no match get missing values:

```
dic = df2.set_index('Z')['Y'].to_dict()

m = df1['Y'].eq('')
#if need test missing values
#m = df1['Y'].isna()
df1.loc[m, 'Y'] = df1['Z'].map(dic)
print (df1)
   Z  Y
0  a  6
1  b  7
2  c  8
3  a  6
4  a  6
```

Comment: @Aham - Some problem?

Comment: @Aham - Added solution in answer in comments, use `m = df1['Y'].isna()` instead `m = df1['Y'].eq('')`

Comment: sorry, I was happy too soon :-( 
I figured my cells look empty but are "NaN" 
I tried to use "np.nan" or "pd.NA" instead of  ' '   to search for the empty cells,
but that does not work.
m results in a lot of "False"
Any ideas what else to use to look for 'NaN? I am not quite sure about the differences to ' '.

Comment: @Aham - can you change `m = df1['Y'].eq('')` to `m = df1['Y'].isna()` in my solution? `isna` is function for check missing values

Comment: sorry, I was editing my comment and thus did not see your answer, I will try .isna

Comment: m = df1['Y'].isna()  finds the empty cells, so I get some "True" in m.
also the dictionary looks fine. Just the mapping does not seem to do anything.
Maybe the matching does not work. I must be overlooking something...

Comment: @Aham - So it means `df2['Z']` not match with `df1['Z']`

Comment: ..now it works fine, I was doing a mistake with the column names. Thank you very much for your help.